# Security.Authenticator - why String user name?

Tags: java, playframework

Authenticators in Play Framework override the `Security.Authenticator` class. One of the methods here is `String getUsername(Context ctx)`.

My question is - why user *name*, why not some general user *ID*? If I were to design such a class, there would be a `Long getUserId(Context ctx)` or `String getUserId(Context ctx)` for cases where GUIDs are used in the DB.

Can anyone shed a light on this?